# como copiar el valor del state de un componente en una variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un estado inicial con un `objeto item` para guardar los datos de personajes. igualo `const model = this.state.item` para poder obterner el objeto y hacer modificaciones pero parece crea una referencia y no una copia. cuando modifico `var body` que es el objeto que utilizo para eliminar y agregar elementos de model tambien se modifica this.state.item

```
  net.on('click', ev => {
  if (!ev.shape) {
    const model =  this.state.item
    var body = model.item.getModel()
    delete body.shape;
    const perid = body.id;
    delete body.id;
    body.per_id = perid;
    body.source = perid;
    var params = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      method: "POST",
      body
    }
    cfetch(params);
```

El problema que tengo es que al obtener el `this.state.item` se modifica y quiero que este no cambie solo hacer una copia en `const model`.

Comment: Creo que te han dado buenas respuestas, pero en react todo eso depende de dónde estés aplicando tu código, ya que si es dentro de un evento, por muchas copias exactas que hagas de tu objeto siempre llamará al `state.item` y puedes no obtener lo que quieres, mi recomendación es que asignes la variable antes de entrar en el evento y ya sea que sea una constante global o algo por el estilo, de lo contrario siempre que la tengas con un valor como `this.state.item` cada que se ejecute esa línea, el valor cambiará

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu lo has dicho se obtiene una **referencia** por lo que aun sigues utilizando el mismo objeto.

La solucion en este caso es hacer una *copia profunda* del objeto asi de hecho estaras *clonando* sus propiedades.

existe una *libreria* [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#cloneDeep) que permite hacer esto de forma simple.

para agregarla al proyecto `npm install -s lodash.clonedeep`
y usarlo de esta forma.

```
 import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';

 const model = cloneDeep(this.state.item);
 var body = model.item.getModel()
 delete body.shape;
```

Comment: Creo que al igualar model al state.item no se creaba  un nuevo objeto apartir de este, algo parecido me paso una  ves con python, no copiaba el objeto solo hacia una referencia. gracias amigo  `lodash/CloneDeep` funciono.

Answer (score 1):

Si estás programando en ES6 puedes hacer uso de deconstruct:

```
const model = { ...this.state.item };
```

También puedes realizarlo con la función Object.assign:

```
const model = Object.assign({}, this.state.item);
```

---

Utililizando deconstruct podrías simplificar aún más el código:

```
const { item: model } = this.state;
```

Por otra parte, como en tu código solo utilizas una vez la variable "model", podrías eliminarla y pasar directamente al método getModel:

```
const { item: { item: { getModel } } =  this.state;
const body = { ...getModel() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Como bien dijiste al asignar un objeto a una variable este crea una referencia en lugar de una copia.

Si quieres realizar una copia de un objeto puedes utilizar [`Object.assing()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/assign), y pasarle un objeto vacío como primer parámetro para crear una copia exacta, un ejemplo funcional adaptado del ejemplo de MDN:

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

// Copia
const object2 = Object.assign({}, object1);

// Referencia
const object3 = object1;

object3.c = 4;

console.log(object1.c, object2.c, object3.c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el objeto no tiene referencias circulares y sin usar librerías externas:

```
const nuevoObjeto = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objetoOriginal));
```